# Runnnig node.js as a windows service

Tags: node.js, windows-services

How to configure [WinSer](http://joseoncode.com/2012/04/06/winser-node-dot-js-applications-as-windows-services) to run a specific javascript file?
I understood that I have to add in package.json the lines:

```
    {
     "name": "MY_SERVICE",
     "scripts": {
      "install-windows-service": "node_modules\\.bin\\winser -i",
      "uninstall-windows-service": "node_modules\\.bin\\winser -r"
    }
```

I couldn't understand where to configure what javascript file I should run?

Answer (score 0):

From a command line in the same folder as your package.json, run

```
winser -i
```

to install your node app (as defined in server.js in the same folder) as a service. Note that if you have not logged off and back on since you installed winser, your path to winser.cmd will not be initialized (it needs something like C:\Users\YourName\AppData\Roaming\npm\ in the path.